# How to repeat a deformation made using geometry nodes on the same plane

Tags: geometry-nodes

I used geometry nodes to form a single whirlpool on a plane (using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkxVUuhugbk) tutorial).

I would like the whirlpool to repeat on the same plane, ideally while being able to control their individual sizes. Is this possible?

This is the node setup and the current result with the desired whirlpools added in blue

[image: node tree]

[image: a whirlpool on a plane with drawn blue spirals around it]

[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately not. You seem to be using node groups, which seem to be part of an additional addon. These are not included in the file, which makes it difficult to look at this in more detail and answer your question.

Comment: @quellenform Ah I see, here is the addon I was using: https://github.com/Gerstmann-Bradley/Mograph-Presets-of-Geometry-Nodes.git, thank you again

Comment: OK, I've looked at this, and I have to be honest: this question is too localized in its current form. To solve your problem, you would first have to analyze all the nodes you used (and Bradley created) and clarify how they work and what exactly they do. It might be easier if you address this directly to the creator of the nodes you use.

Comment: @quellenform I disagree, the example is localized, but I think the question, if anything, is too simple: how do you want to repeat the deformation? Just duplicate the modifier. Obviously this would stack the whirlpool onto itself, but if it displaces the mesh based on e.g. distance from origin, you could modify the node tree to be based on a distance of a supplied (input) coordinate instead. Then after duplicating the modifier you would just pass e.g. $(0; 0; 0)$, $(-0.75; -0.75; 0)$, $(-0.75; 0.75; 0)$, $(0.75; 0.75; 0)$,  $(0.75; -0.75; 0)$ as the coordinates.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Then please be so kind and write an answer that is understandable for *Geometry Nodes* newbies. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a whirlpool node setup like this:

[image]

Obviously, just stacking it on itself will deepen the whirlpool rather than add more whirlpools:

[image]

So the solution is to create an input controlling the position of the whirlpool - in my case I can just add an offset to the coordinate space, add it to the currently evaluated position and use this node setup instead of a simple Position node:

[image]

Now you can duplicate the geonode modifiers and change the offset for each:

[image]

Comment: Yes, completely replacing those weird nodes with something usable is obviously the better option! :D Well done!