# How to make circular transform texture coordinate?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am trying to make circular transform texture coordinates so that I can add a gradient to achieve the given result.

[image]

Input can be a gradient, noise, or just a white value but it should transform in the circular transform with parameters Inner Margin, Outer Margin, Repetitions, and Swirl.

E.g. this result where:

Input is a gradient with parameters
`Inner Margin = 0.25`, `Outer Margin = 0.75`, `Repetitions = 2` ,`Swirl = 1`

[image]

`Repetitions = 2`, Repetitions should increase the number of radial lines

[image]=

`Swirl = 1`, Swirl should curve the radial lines

[image]

`Repetitions` is the number of lines and `Swirl` is the amount of curve to those lines

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276363/60486

Comment: Could you define what you are expecting from the Repetitions and Swirl parameters ? I understand Repetitions as duplicates in radial direction, and Swirl as turns. So Swirl=1 means 1 turn to recover the pattern ; Swirl=2 means 2 turns to recover the pattern; Swirl=0 means 0 turn, so axisymmetric (only radial variations).

Comment: `Repetitions` is the number of lines and `Swirl` is the amount of curve to those lines

Comment: What kind of gradient is used in your examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

#### Objective

[image: Objective]

To render a picture such as Fig. 1, the apparent transformation of a texture map such as shown Fig. 2, is to duplicate it in the azimuthal direction by the factor *Repetitions* as shown Fig. 3 (where *Repetitions* is set to 2), to shear it in the azimuthal direction proportionally to radius by the factor *Swirl* as shown Fig. 4 (where *Swirl* is set to 0.25, i.e. a quarter of turn), and finally to wrap it between radius *Inner Margin* and *Outer Margin* (set respectively to 0.25 and 0.75 in these figures). *Inner Margin* and *Outer Margin* are non-dimensional parameters, i.e. defined for a circle of radius 1.

#### Approach

Because in Blender a *Texture* node can not be connected at a *NodeGroup* input socket, the process has to be reversed.

[image: Main GN]
**1.** The world coordinates are transformed to the texture coordinates, i.e. a square with $(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$, as shown Fig. 2.
**2.** The chosen *Texture* node computes the *Color* from the *Position Vector* defined in the texture coordinates system.
**3.** Radius lower than *Inner Margin* or greater than *Outer Margin* are rendered in black using a mask.
**4.** The resulting *Color* is input to the *Shader* node.
**5.** To switch between textures, a *Mix* node can be inserted before the *Shader* node.

#### Shading nodes

##### From Cartesian to polar coordinates, in world coordinates system

[image: GN polar coordinates]
**1.** The world coordinates of the surface to shade are transformed in a square domain $(X,Y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$, based on the surface bounding box, using a [*Texture Coordinate*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html) node.
**2.** $(X,Y)$ are scaled and shifted to vary between -1 and 1, instead of 0 and 1. The polar coordinates system origin is thus $(0,0)$, and the largest circle radius is 1. 
**3.** The radius $R$ is computed as $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.
**4.** The angle $\theta$ is computed such that $\tan{\theta}=-\frac{X}{Y}$. $\theta$ origin is thus set at the +Y Axis, and $\theta$ is increasing counter-clock wise, with $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$.

##### From world to texture coordinates systems

[image: GN Spiral]
**1.** The radius is directly mapped to the $y$ axis of the texture coordinates system, such that *Outer Margin* is associated to $y=0$, and *Inner Margin* to $y=1$. This choice is arbitrary.
**2.** The angle is mapped to the $x$ axis of the texture coordinates system with some transformations. First, the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is mapped to $[0,1]$.
**3.** Then, a shift $\delta x$ proportional to $y$ and to the *Swirl* parameter is **subtracted** (because of the reversed process) from $x$. Mapping *Outer Margin* to $y=0$ yields no angular displacement at the external boundary.
**4.** The *Repetitions* parameter is used to scale $x$.
**5.** Finally, $x$ is folded back between 0 and 1 using a [*Warp*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/render/shader_nodes/converter/math.html) node.
**6.** A B&W color mask to blacken radius greater than *Outer Margin* is made using *Map Range* and *Color Ramp* nodes.
**7.** A B&W color mask to blacken radius lower than *Inner Margin* is made using *Map Range* and *Color Ramp* nodes.
**8.** Both B&W color masks are combined in a single mask.

#### Resources

- Blender file: [image]
- To switch between textures, see [Is there an easy way to create a model with multiple texture inputs and then easily switch between them?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-model-with-multiple-texture-inputs-and-then-eas).
- About creating a *NodeGroup* that has a *Texture* node as an input, see [Add an image texture to a shader subgraph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160771/add-an-image-texture-to-a-shader-subgraph).

Comment: hello, @StefLAncien, how to add bevel to circular transform node group?https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309463/how-to-add-bevel-to-circular-transform-node-group

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what the *swirl* and *repetition* is, so I made some assumptions.

[image: node tree and result]

Use the length from the center and map it to a new range. That is how you can control the inner and outer radius. The radial setup, which you posted in the question, can be substituted with the *Gradient Texture* node. By subtracting these values from one another, you can create the swirl.

---

If you want to modify coordinates by rotating them, use the *Vector Rotate* node.

[image: vector rotate node to rotate vector coordinates]

Comment: For information, I've tested it: I obtain something similar but with other input values for the radii (I don't think I'm mistaken in the setting?). But as it is, the result is black on a simple plane. Could be due to the UV map itself.

Comment: I want the vector as an output so that I can use that in other textures e.g. noise, gradient

Comment: @Karan: could you please share your Blender file with https://blend-exchange.com/ to help us to understand how you would like to "plug" the vector you are expecting ?

Comment: @Karan Sorry for the misunderstanding. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 4):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*
*NB: this is an incomplete answer, to clarify what is expected.*

> Answer fully documented is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309345/177431).

#### First edition

Such results
[image: Results]
are achieved with the following nodes graph:
[image: GN Graph]

#### Second edition

Following is a proposal converting cylindrical $(R,\theta)$ world coordinates to (x,y) texture coordinates. These can be input to texture nodes, such as a *Gradient Texture* node.
[image: Spiral to square transformation]

**Resources:**[image]

#### Third edition

Following is a proposal for the data flow because a *Texture* node can not be an *Input* to *NodeGroup*. *Texture* nodes have to be "downstream" of *NodeGroup*.
[image: Main node graph]

Comment: @Karan: I understand from your comment on [Leander's proposal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309285/177431) that this is not the graph you are expecting. Please share your Blender file, so I could tailor this proposal.

Comment: Is it possible to have the gradient or noise as input, then the circular transform will transform it as described in the question?

Comment: Input can be a gradient or a noise or just a white value but it should transform in the circular transform with parameters `Inner Margin`, `Outer Margin`, `Repetitions` and `Swirl`

Comment: @Karan: I am trying a second proposal, where instead of a color ramp, a gradient texture node is used. Is this more in line with your expectations ? The Blender file is available to try by yourself. I will clean this answer and write detailed explanations after your feedback.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Can you do me a favor and make another edition, can you make it in a way that takes the gradient or any input and transforms it? e.g. it takes the gradient as the input and transforms it. Input can be anything e.g. checker pattern, brick pattern etc.

Comment: @Karan: If I understand correctly your expectation, you would like a NodeGroup with a Texture as input socket and a Color as output socket ? If so, I am afraid this is not possible with current Blender versions as Texture is not supported as input (see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161086/177431). You can see supported input types in Shading Editor opening the "Group/Inputs" tab on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I realized it may not be very clear in the [linked geonodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276363/60486) answer, so I decided to also add a shader screenshot here:

[image]

there's a simple relation here between the ping-pong value ($p$), the multiply value ($m$) and the number of arms ($a$), which can be expressed as $$a = |{m \over p}| ÷ 2$$ (multiply the ping-pong value by 2 and then by the number of arms you want)